# Pandas apply function issue

Tags: python, function, pandas

I have a dataframe (data) of numeric variables and I want to analyse the distribution of each column by using the Shapiro test from scipy.

```
from scipy import stats
data.apply(stats.shapiro, axis=0)
```

But I keep getting the following error message:

```
ValueError: ('could not convert string to float: M', u'occurred at index 0')
```

I've checked the documentation and it says the first argument of the apply function should be a function, which stats.shapiro is (as far as I'm aware).

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does your variable 'data' have any strings in it?

Comment: To add onto my earlier comment, if you go `data[0]`, is it the string 'M'?

Comment: @nbrayans well actually, the problem is that there is a string in the *column* 0 of the `DataFrame` `data`. So, OP needs to check if there is a string `M` somewhere in the column returned by `data.iloc[:,0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. There was a column of type object which resulted in the error message above. Apply the function only to numeric columns solved this issue.